# cannot display an image with a do while in the OnCreate method

Tags: android, image

I'm trying to draw an image inside a do while in the `OnCreate` method but it fails to show.

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE); 
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN); 

    drawElements();
}

public void drawElements(){
     do{
         RelativeLayout layout = new RelativeLayout(this);
   RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(80, 60);
params.setMargins(0, 0, 0, 0);
   ImageView image = new ImageView(this);
personaje.setImageResource(R.drawable.image);
layout.addView(image, params);
      setContentView(layout);
      Log.i("MainActivity","here comes");
     }while(!esc)
    }
```

It's strange because it comes in the `do while`, because the log shows constantly on the LogCat but the image does not show.

In fact, it fails to remove the status bar or the title of the application as specified in the `onCreate`, but if I remove the do while it shows everything correctly.

Any suggestions?

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish with the while loop?  Multiple images?  Where is esc defined?  When does it change?  I don't think this code makes any sense.

Comment: the esc is defined before the onCreate method. it's a bool that when a key is pressed  the value is changed to true and the loop stops working. I try to make it to foresee the same image and when you press a keyboard arrow for example modify the position of the image. I'm trying to make a classic structure for a game.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to rethink your whole design.  What you are doing here does not make any sense.

Your while loop is going to loop forever, blocking the UI thread.  Thus, nothing will ever be displayed.

Instead, you should display a single image in `onCreate`.  Add a key listener or button listener that will change the image within the listener.

Comment: I do not know if this is possible with this language and platform, but I did the same in other languages like C, C++ or AS and it worked perfectly. Here seems to be permeating the GUI... The esc in the other cases was to terminate the application and close the window.

Comment: You need to read through the basic documentation to understand how Android works.  You should never do blocking things, like wait for an async event, on the UI thread.  That just doesn't make any sense.